# fix encoding Arabic data from database

Tags: php, database, encoding, arabic

fix encoding Arabic data from database ?

```
    function postTitle()
            {
        $postdb = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wtable");
        $post = mysql_fetch_assoc($postdb);
            echo mb_detect_encoding($post['posttitle'],"UTF-8,ISO-8859-1");
            }
echo postTitle();
```

*datebase encode: utf8_general_ci*

**result:**

```
????????? ?????????????? ????????? ????? ???????
```

Comment: do you know the encoding of the database fields?

Comment: Are you printing to something that supports UTF-8?  If you are printing to a browser, are you sending the correct encoding header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the script is encoded UTF8 too, be sure that the connection also uses UTF8:
Use this:

```
mysql_query('SET names UTF8');
```

....before the SELECT inside the function.